# Should I run Docker command on Windows or Docker command line?

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I use the following command in order to backup Postgresql database on Docker, but as I run the command on Windows Powershell, it throws error "'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command windows winrar or zip".

```
cmd /c "docker exec -t my-container pg_dump my_db -c -U postgres | gzip > C:\\backup\\my_db.gz"
```

**1.** Can I use WinRar with this command as archiver?

**2.** Is it better to use this kind of commands on Docker command line instead of Windows Powershell in order to use Linux specific featıures e.g. gzip?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to accomplish what you want to do on a Windows computer using that command `unmodified` is to download the Console Emulator Cmder

https://cmder.net

Make sure you download the full version (with Git for windows), then all Unix commands are readily available in the Windows path (including gzip, which is what you want in the first place).

Comment: I have already using it. SHould I open tab Gitbash?

Comment: Just open {cmd::Cmder}

Comment: Very interesting, I have used cmder for this purpose but with PowerShell and using cmd seems to be working. But why? Normally I thought that Powershell is much better for running Docker commands? Any idea?

Comment: And I get an error as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67749058/postgresql-restore-command-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0x. Do you have and solution for that?